# Dynamically generating foreach

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, foreach

I'm trying to write a function that do the following :
Let's say i have an array :

```php
$data = array(
    array('10','15','20','25'),
    array('Blue','Red','Green'),
    array('XL','XS')
)
```

and my result array should be like :

```php
$result = array(
    array('10','15','20','25'),
    array('Blue','Red','Green','Blue','Red','Green','Blue','Red','Green','Blue','Red','Green')
    array('XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS','XL','XS')
)
```

Im stuck with this because i want a function that is able to do this no matter how much array there is in the first array `$data`

I have only been able to write this, which is what give the `$result` array :

```php
foreach($data[2] as $value2){
    $result[2][] = $value2;
    foreach($data[1] as $value1){
        $result[1][] = $value1;
        foreach($data[0] as $value0){
            $result[0][] = $value0;
        }
    }
}
```

After a few research, it seems that a recursive function is the way to go in order to dynamically generate those `foreach` but i can't get it to work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is dynamic:

```
$result[] = array_shift($data);

foreach($data as $value) {
    $result[] = call_user_func_array('array_merge',
                                     array_fill(0, count($result[0]), $value));
}
```

- Get and remove the first element from original
- Loop remaining elements and fill result with values X number of values in first element
- Since the elements were arrays merge them all into result

If modifying the original is unwanted, then use this method:

```
$result[] = reset($data);

while($value = next($data)) {
    $result[] = call_user_func_array('array_merge',
                                     array_fill(0, count($result[0]), $value));
}
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: result in /tmp/execpad-f98c9926d5ea/source-f98c9926d5ea on line 15

Warning: array_merge() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in /tmp/execpad-f98c9926d5ea/source-f98c9926d5ea on line 15

Warning: array_merge() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in /tmp/execpad-f98c9926d5ea/source-f98c9926d5ea on line 15
`

Comment: Yes, now i's ok

Comment: Well, this is perfectly what i was trying to achieve, except that i need to use `count($result[$key])` instead of `count($result[0])` ! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

just use array_fill and array_merge functions

```
$result = array(
  $data[0],
  array_merge(...array_fill(0,count($data[0]), $data[1])),
  array_merge(...array_fill(0,count($data[0])*count($data[0]), $data[2]))
  );
print_r($result);
```

**[demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/785614)**

Comment: Your solution works great but i didn't know how to proceed to use your answer when i dont know the number of element in `$data`. AbraCadaver answer seems more flexible and easy to use in a function, but thank you for your help !